# Add default controls when you add a control tab

Tags: c#, .net

I am making a program where you can click a button and a new tab will be made in a tab control. But without any controls, I can't figure out if you can place those controls everytime when the user creates a new tab page.

My code atm:

```
private void newJobBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage("NewTab " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString());

            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
        }
```

Comment: `Button pageButton = new Button(); myTabPage.Controls.Add(pageButton);`

Comment: @LibertyLocked Thanks for your comment but is it also possible to set the position?

Comment: `pageButton.Location = new Point(20, 20);` Before you ask how to set color, size, onclick, etc, see [How to programmatically add controls to Windows forms at run time by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319266)

Comment: @LibertyLocked Thanks a lot I thought this would not work because if you add 2 tabs then there would be 2 buttons with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand what you are trying to do, I would create a UserControl that contains the Controls that are required for your TabPage, then create a new TabPage that adds your usercontrol to it, and then adds the TabPage to your TabControl.

```
TabPage tp = new TabPage("Tab Page " + (tabControl1.TabPages.Count +1).ToString());
tp.Controls.Add(new UserControl1());
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but let's say I would like to add a textbox to the tab. Then I wan't to edit the text from the textbox in a specific tab. Is this possible to do?

Comment: This is possible.  I would suggest that you investigate how UserControls work. check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388333/how-to-use-usercontrol-in-window-forms-programming-c-sharp) to get started.

Comment: Thanks for that link I will definitely check it out!